# Scala: reduceByKey for finding maximum in tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have simple rdd looks like

```
scala> gp_by_cls.collect
res82: Array[(Int, (Int, Int))] = Array((3,(1,26)), (1,(0,37)), (3,(0,77)), (1,(2,914)), (2,(1,13)), (1,(1,25)), (2,(2,893)), (3,(2,1661)), (2,(0,42)))
```

I want to get the maximum of ._2 for each key (1661, 914, 893), so I did

```
scala> gp_by_cls.reduceByKey{case((a,b),(c,d)) => b if (b > d) else d}
```

but get the following error:

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'if' found.
gp_by_cls.reduceByKey{case((a,b),(c,d)) => b if (b > d) else d}
                                             ^
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `if (b > d) b else d` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReducebyKey accepts as parameter a function that returns the same type of the values in your PairRDD, in this case your `RDD` is `RDD[(Int, (Int, Int)]` so the return type needs to be `(Int, Int)`, your function should be:

```
gp_by_cls.reduceByKey{
    case ((a, b), (c, d)) => if(b > d) (a, b) else (c, d)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `if` statement has a problem. It should be `if (b > d) b else d`
2. You cannot use `reduceByKey` function after you do a `collect` over an RDD. As long as it is still an `RDD`/`DataFrame`/`Dataset`, you can perform your `reduceByKey`